# Saving "if-statements" and stats via shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, bundle

I´m working on an Quizz-App and would like to create an level-up-game. If the user scores more then 5 points the button "klasse 2" is supposed to change the color.
Now if 5 points are achieved it changes the color like it´s supposed to do. The only problem is that if i close the app or press the back button the color is gone and the old color appears.

I dont know what i did wrong with the sharedPrefs. As i am a begginer im not very into this topic and hope u guys can help me out a bit.

Thanks!

```
public class Levels extends AppCompatActivity {


Button klasse1, klasse2, klasse3, klasse4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_levels);

    klasse1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.class1btn);klasse2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.class2btn);
    klasse3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.class3btn);klasse4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.class4btn);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bundle != null){
        int score = bundle.getInt("finaleScore");
        if (score >= 5){

            klasse2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

       }
        saveData(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        saveData(score);

    }

    klasse1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openK1 = new Intent(Levels.this, Class1.class);
            startActivity(openK1);
        }
    });

}

public void saveData(int t){
    SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("instrasparent", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();
    mEditor.putInt("instransparentField", t);
    mEditor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent backMain = new Intent(Levels.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(backMain);

}
```

}

Comment: is this activity is your start Activity of App?

Comment: No, it´s the "menu" or "level-up" menu. When the user has finished the first lvl quiz he will come back to this activity. If he hits the 5 points or more the color changes and he can continue playing with "klasse2". If he instead hit 4 or less the color won´t change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you are dealing with SharedPreferences in other activity, but from your current code, you are overwriting the res by scores in SharedPreferences. You are saving background and scores on the same key.

```
saveData(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
saveData(score);
```

Try something this:

```
saveData(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), score);


...

public void saveData(int col, int scores){
    SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("instrasparent", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPrefs.edit();
    mEditor.putInt("instransparentFieldCol", col);
    mEditor.putInt("instransparentFieldScore", scores);
    mEditor.commit();
}
```

And in the **onResume** you shoud update the code and color.

Comment: No Problem Steigy :)

Answer (score 2):

Once you open new activity, maybe you need to close previous activity. You can use finish().

One more thing, when you want to go back to previous activity, you have make Bundle to transfer all the value to previous activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(Levels.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saving the color Id and Score in same Prefrences Key , Use different keys to save Color Id and Score

Answer (score 0):

The previous `Activity` in your stack does not have the new color loaded, although you saved it into SavedPreferences.
Try overriding the `onResume()` method of your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Check if the color changed loading it in SharedPreferences, and change it if needed
}
```

This way, when you go back, your `Activity` will check if the color should change, and handle it properly.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I forgot the onResume Method :)